# Serving https in aurelia typescript webpack dev setup

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I need to use `https://localhost:8080` for testing facebook login in development when I run `au run` so that the app uses https instead of http.

The current setup is using the standard aurelia+typescript+webpack skeleton created from `au new`.

I added `https: true` to devServer field in my webpack.config.js but it doesn't work. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-https. Do I need to do anything special for Aurelia?

Comment: Would love to help you. But what is your question?
where in config is the setting for serving up your app?

Comment: Added more info. I just want the webpack dev server to serve https instead of http when I run ```au run```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like an oversight in the `run.ts` task. The `https` property is not being copied over.

If you make this modification it should work:

```
function runWebpack(done) {
  // https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html
  let opts = {
    host: 'localhost',
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    filename: config.output.filename,
    hot: project.platform.hmr || CLIOptions.hasFlag('hmr'),
    port: project.platform.port,
    contentBase: config.output.path,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    open: project.platform.open,
    stats: {
      colors: require('supports-color')
    },
    https: config.devServer.https // add this line
  }
```

I submitted a [PR](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/pull/865) that should fix this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I accepted your answer. Would you please update it to use config.devServer.https?

Comment: Darn, I actually tested it and somehow managed to mess it up in the answer. Thanks for pointing this out!