# Aurelia to run https on dev environment

Tags: aurelia

Currently I am working on an Aurelia app that is fully developed. In the dev environment, it is only serving http requests. Anyone could help me with adding https so can I can access the app through https?

Thank you

Angelo

Comment: Hi, Angelo. This depends on the bundler you are using. Webpack? Alameda?

Comment: I am using Webpack

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serving https in aurelia typescript webpack dev setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49687797/serving-https-in-aurelia-typescript-webpack-dev-setup)

Comment: Hi Cristian, thanks. I did have a look at it, That solution was back in 2018 and it also talks about them updating Aurelia to fix it. I see run-webpack.ts having that setting (https: config.devServer.https) in folder node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\resources\tasks and my webpack.config.js has this setting : 
 devServer: {
    contentBase: outDir,
    // serve index.html for all 404 (required for push-state)
    historyApiFallback: true,
 https: true
  },
Is there anything else I am missing? thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the webpack.config.js file, add the https property:

```
devServer: {
    ... some other values...
    https: true
    ... some other values...
  },
```

With that, you should run

```
npm start
```

And you'll get your app running on https://localhost:8080

Regards.